# Angular add button content to array on click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

so What I want is, on button click add item.name to a new array :

```
<button (click)="addDistrict(item.name)" *ngFor="let item of items" ion-button>{{item.name}}</button>

myDist = [];

addDistrict(item.name){
   this.myDist.push(item.name)
  }
```

How to do that properly ?

Comment: addDistrict(item.name) <--- throws syntax errors

Comment: because in ts file item.name is unknown

Comment: use `addDistrict(item)` and `this.myDist.push(item)`

Comment: Are you sure your object has the property "name" in it?

Comment: You should also post your .html template and typescript file (not entirely but your interfaces and the click event handler would be helpful)

Comment: (item) only worked. Now Understand. Miquel thats all I use.

Comment: As @tftd answered your declaration of addDistrict is incorrect.

For this case you may use ```addDistrict(districtName: string): void {
this.myDist.push(districtName);
}``` for your method declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer posted by @tftd is correct and which solve your problem too. But I would write something like this:

In HTML:

```
// Will pass the object in to the method like

<button (click)="addDistrict(item)" *ngFor="let item of items" ion-button> 
   {{item.name}}
</button>
```

and in TS file:

```
addDistrict(item){
   // will extract the related key from Object here to push it in array
   this.myDist.push(item.name);
}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dywmam)

Answer (score 1):

Your `addDistrict` function's argument is incorrect as well as the varialbe you are passing to it from the template.

In the template you are passing `item.name` which is a string and then in the function you have `item.name` again (which yould fail because you can't have a variable name containing a dot). This should work

```
addDistrict(name){
    this.myDist.push(name)
}
```